# Use RPi.GPIO with Python 3.6

Tags: gpio, python-3.6

I try to use RPi.GPIO with Python 3.6.
I installed RPi.GPIO and it's working with Python 3.4, but not with Python 3.6
I get this Error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'

I immport the module in my script like this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

Answer (score 6):

Add this line to the top of your *.py file:

`#!/usr/bin/env python3.6`

Run these commands in your shell:

```
sudo python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
sudo python3.6 -m pip install RPi.GPIO
```

This should fix the Problem.
By this you will install RPi.GPIO for the right python version. In this case 3.6.x.